# Sending a UDP packet acknowledgment every so often - Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I'm currently writing a simple client/server UDP file transfer program in Python. I'm currently trying to implement some measures for ensuring total data delivery. While I understand that UDP isn't known for reliability, I must use UDP for the transfer (I'm simply working on a test program for a larger project, and the device being used in that project isn't capable of using TCP streams).

Anyways, as it stands, I'm able to get all data across to the client, by implementing a simple ACK system in which the client sends an ACK for every packet it receives. However, this is slowing down the transfer speed (not terribly, but enough that I'd like to optimize it).

My idea to reduce the speed would be to send an ACK only every so often (instead of for each packet). The frequency with which an ACK should be sent would likely be determined upon amount of data received (i.e. every x bytes), or packets received (i.e. every x number of packets).

However, I'm struggling to implement this on top of my current system below:

Server:

```
if(numSent >= 100):
            print "Waiting for an ACK now..."
            conn.settimeout(2)
            try:
                ACK = conn.recv(tcp_buf)
                print "ACK: " + ACK
                ackF.write(ACK+"\n")
            except socket.timeout:
                isClientCaughtUp = False
                conn.settimeout(None)
            if (isClientCaughtUp is False):
                if(s.sendto(chunk,addr) and s.sendto(str(local_ID),addr)):
                    ACK = conn.recv(tcp_buf)
                    ackF.write(ACK + "\n")
                    if (ACK):
                        isClientCaughtUp = True
                        conn.settimeout(2)
                        break
                    numSent = 0
```

Client:

```
try:
    while(dataChunk):
        actualNumChunks += 1
        count += 1 
        f.write(dataChunk)
        sock.settimeout(6)
        dataChunk, addr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        packID, junkAddr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        if(count >= 100):
            #print "ACK sent!"
            tcp_sock.send("1")
            count = 0
except socket.timeout:
    f.close()
    sock.close()
```

Right now, I believe that I'm having issues with the sockets timing out. The server isn't sending all of its packets, nor is it receiving any acknowledgments. This was a very slight modification to my original code that had me sending/receiving an ACK for every packet sent. Also, I'm only sending junk ACKs for right now.

Additionally, the program works by communicating (ACKs, and some other stuff) via TCP, while the data itself is sent via UDP. They are two different sockets.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing protocol like TFTP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work. The side sending data can only do it using a pure UDP transfer (and even that's stretching it). It lacks the capabilities for more complex things like TCP. On my end (the side receiving data), I just need to be able to receive that data and possibly request dropped packets. So, I'm not sure if TFTP would work, as the sending side is limited by what it can use. If, however, I can use TFTP to receive just a regular UDP datagram, then I'd be interested to hear more.

Comment: My assumption (correct my if I'm wrong), is that TFTP requires that the sender has the proper libraries, or whatever to use TFTP. Is that correct?

Comment: TFTP is a file transfer protocol that uses UDP as the transport layer.

Comment: So, how would I go about using that? I've found tftpy http://tftpy.sourceforge.net/sphinx/index.html (since I'm using Python). For tftpy, it looks like both server and client need to have the software installed (which doesn't work for me)